# R: how to make a loop of MCMCglmm

Tags: r, loops, glm

I want to transform my gene expression data by exacting the phylogenetic signal from the data. I use R package MCMCglmm.
I can apply MCMCglmm to one of the expression column:

```
require(ape)
library("MCMCglmm")
expr1 <- c(5,6,5, 11,12,13, 32,33,36)
expr2 <- c(1100,1212,1333, 32,33,36, 34, 38, 49)
expr3 <- c(32,33,36, 110,120,130, 320,330,360)
animal <- seq.int(9)
popGroup <- c(rep('A', 3),rep('B', 3), rep('C', 3))
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(expr1, expr2, expr3, animal, popGroup))
class(data$expr1)<-'integer'
class(data$expr3)<-'integer'
class(data$expr2)<-'integer'

# tree file content:
# (((1:2.0,(2:1.0,3:1.0):1.0):3.0,((4:1.0,5:1.0):1.0,6:2.0):3.0):3.0,(7:2.0,(8:1.0,9:1.0):1.0):6.0);
tree <- read.tree("tree.nwk")

prior<-list(R=list(V=1, nu=1), G=list(G1=list(V=1, nu=1)))
summary(MCMCglmm(expr1~popGroup-1, random=~animal, pedigree=tree, data=data, family="poisson", prior = prior))
```

but I have more than 20000 of such columns. So, my idea is to loop through all of them:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  M <- ( (colnames(data)[i]~popGroup-1, random=~animal, pedigree=tree, data=data, family="poisson", prior = prior))
  summM <- summary(M)
  statM <- summM$statistics[,1:2]
  print(statM)
}
```

The problem is in defining the response variable in the loop. I tried many ways, but none works.

Comment: You can easily vectorise your function over all columns using the `sapply` or `lapply` functions. Here's an example returning a statistic from a simple `lm`: `sapply(data[,1:3], function(x) { M <- lm(data[,i] ~ data$popGroup) ; summM <- summary(M) ; statM <- summM$adj.r.squared ; statM })`

Comment: The problem I found was in referring to the column names within the `MCMCglmm()` expression, as the function doesn't seem to deal with variables being referred to in the format `data$var1` or `data[,"var2"]`, and instead defining the dataframe in the `data=...` argument. Perhaps someone else can help!

Comment: @jogal, thanks for your attempt to help. Yes, the problem is in how `MCMCglmm()` deals with variables.
For `glm()` it works flawlessly:
`for (i in 1:3) {
  M <- glm(data[,i]~popGroup-1, data=data, family="poisson"));
  summM <- summary(M);
  print(summM)
}`

Comment: Try `formula(paste(...))` the expression.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, thank you for your suggestion. I didn't get your idea first, but than I received a reply from Jarrod Hadfield, the author of the package `MCMCglmm`, and he advised the same way. I posted his reply below as an answer to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution from Jarrod Hadfield, the author of the package `MCMCglmm`:

> Unfortunately MCMCglmm works slightly differently than `glm` when
>   defining response variables. What you could do is:
>
> > fixed<-as.formula(paste(colnames(data)[i], "~popGroup-1", sep=""))
> >
> > MCMCglmm(fixed=fixed, ...)

The script works now.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted @dmkr. This really should be included in the package's help page.